# Catched ActivitiException still gets thrown and breaks application

Tags: java, activiti, atomikos

I'm having trouble understanding what is happening and why my loop doesn't continue. I'm creating a dashboard for all open activiti tasks. Now the trouble i am having is when someone closes a task while the dashboard is being created.

The code is like this:

```
List<Task> approvalTasks = taskQueryApproval.list();
for (Task task : approvalTasks) {
    try {
        ActivitiApplicationRequest activitiRequest = (ActivitiApplicationRequest) taskService
                .getVariable(task.getId(), ACTIVITIREQUEST);
        if (!dashboardValues.containsKey(activitiRequest.getGlobalRequestId())) {
            GlobalRequest globalRequest = globalRequestDao
                .findMinimalGlobalRequestForDashboardBySyscode(activitiRequest.getGlobalRequestId());
            if (globalRequest != null) {
                DashboardValueObject vo = new DashboardValueObject(globalRequest);
                vo.setHasApproval(true);
                dashboardValues.put(activitiRequest.getGlobalRequestId(), vo);
            }
        }
        } catch (ActivitiException ex) {
            LOGGER.debug("Approval already done, skipping activititask");
        }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is I know when the task doesn't exist Activiti is going to throw an exception, that's why I placed a try-catch inside the for loop.

What I'm expecting is that when the error is catched it just continues with the rest of the list. While debugging I even saw the catch being done. But the loop still breaks and the application stops. With these exceptions :

```
SEVERE: Error while closing command context org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: task 203039 doesn't exist
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.GetTaskVariableCmd.execute(GetTaskVariableCmd.java:55)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:42)

9-nov-2012 14:45:42 org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext close
SEVERE: Error while closing command context
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: The transaction has timed out - try increasing the timeout if needed
### The error may exist in org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/Task.xml
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.selectTask
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: select * from ACT_RU_TASK where ID_ = ?
### Cause: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: The transaction has timed out - try increasing the timeout if needed
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:81)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your service @Transactional ? The transaction has timed out. It sounds like a lock problem on your database.

Comment: @willome The service itself that is called is from Activiti. Now in the source code I don't see the annotation. The timeout just comes instantly after the ActivitiException is thrown.

Comment: Check your debug logs. Do you see any rollback ?

Comment: @willome Yes after the transaction times out it fires off a rollback aswell. And yes I'm using spring

Comment: Could you try to add a @transactional with a "norollbackfor" ActivitiException

Comment: Or better : set your try/catch into a new @transaction(REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: @willome But it is not my service tho, it is Activiti's task service